# Java applet dependencies fetched multiple times

Tags: java, applet, jaxb

Web application I'm currently investigating embeds `<applet>`, which has several dependencies (.jar files).

Applet tag looks like that:

```
<applet ...
        type="application/x-java-applet"
        codebase="/webapp/applet">
     ...
     <param name="codebase" value="./applet"/>
     <param name="archive" value="a.jar,b.jar,c.jar"/>
     <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false"/>
</applet>
```

Applet works OK, but the problem is, that when it loads for the **first time**, those a.jar, b.jar, c.jar, etc. are being **requested** (and downloaded) from web server **MANY (20-300) times**, each, which makes applet start-up quite slow.

Whats going on, are jars being re-downloaded for each loaded class separately?

Is there a way to optimize/configure applet properly? Tried several caching tricks (like `<param name="cache_archive" />` , but no success and not even sure it's right way to approach this problem.

NB! this applet is **WS client** (has some **JAXB**-annotated classes and related dependencies).

---

Applet log on start-up has plenty of those:

```
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/a.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/a.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/a.jar with proxy=DIRECT
... ~100 more times a.jar is downloaded
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/a.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/b.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/b.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/c.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/a.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://127.0.0.1:7001/webapp/applet/c.jar with proxy=DIRECT
...
```

Web server access log reflects applet log:

```
127.0.0.1 - "GET /webapp/applet/a.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1232582 
127.0.0.1 - "GET /webapp/applet/a.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1232582 
127.0.0.1 - "GET /webapp/applet/a.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1232582 
...
127.0.0.1 - "GET /webapp/applet/a.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 1232582
```

Comment: Is there an URL we can visit the applet?

Comment: No, that's an internal app, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because in **CXF** `URL.openStream()` was used to access different resources from jars (schemas, wsdls, etc).

Issue was solved by replacing `URL.openStream()` with `getResourceAsStream()` method from **classloader** (apparently `Applet2ClassLoader.getResource().openStream()` makes unnecessary connection and `Applet2ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` does not).

Update: it seems to be working on Java7 Plugin, but not Java6 one.