# Java Web Start - Ignoring/changing Jar href URL's

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a JNLP file which is created via  a PHP script. It outputs something like the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="/" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>sometitle</title>
        <vendor>somevendor</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>somedesc</description>
        <description kind="short">someshort</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/jar/e43e034c49c4a24f2711d385370faaf1ef92ca76" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="http://fproject.localhost/getjava/libs/lib/httpmime-4.2.3.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="Windows8.Windows8GUI">

    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

The application loads and initially opens fine, however the application is slow and unresponsive, after taking a look at my apache access log there seems to be some strange happenings, well first of all, it loads all the jars successfully:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:56 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 24509 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:56 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 65294 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:56 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/ba1df5097852421a791d095271fd48df6c79804c HTTP/1.1" 200 14060 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:56 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 253503 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:57 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 469073 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:57 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 124242 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:57 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 245191 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:39:57 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/httpmime-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 29955 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
```

Then there are loads of requests for the same files but the location has changed:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:02 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:03 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:03 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:03 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:03 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:04 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:04 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:05 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:05 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:05 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpmime-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:06 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 124242 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:06 +0000] "GET /getjava/libs/lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 245191 "-" "JNLP/1.7.0 javaws/10.13.2.20 (<internal>) Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:06 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:06 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:07 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:07 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:07 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpmime-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:08 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2013:19:40:08 +0000] "GET /getjava/jar/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar HTTP/1.1" 404 2011 "-" "Java/1.7.0_13"
```

Notice that /getjava/libs/lib has changed to /getjava/jar/lib

How is this so? Where is the JVM getting this URL from?

And more so, why does the JVM request the same file over and over again?

**Edit - More information**

I think I've narrowed the problem down a little bit. I'm pretty sure it's to do with Netbeans. I'm using version 7.2.1.

It seems that the URLS for the extra library requests are coming from the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in the main application Jar. In there I can see the following:

```
Class-Path: lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar li
 b/fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar lib/httpclient-cache-4
 .2.3.jar lib/httpcore-4.2.2.jar lib/httpmime-4.2.3.jar
```

This would explain the modified URL's and the subsequent 404 responses as these files are not available at that URL.

I don't understand why Netbeans is creating this paths of files. I am under the impression that Java Webstart downloads its resources using the JNLP file, and with in that the `<resources>` node?

How can I stop netbeans adding this `Class-Path` attribute as I believe this is the root of my problem.

**Further Updates**

I have found a work around to this problem through hacking through files. If I take out this line:

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
```

from this file:

```
nbproject\build-impl.xml
```

Then Netbeans compiles the Jar correctly for a Webstart App. It does not create the `Class-Path` atttribute in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the Jar. After removing this the app works absolutely fine, no hangs and no bogus requests for files which do not exist.

Now I guess the question is, why does Netbeans do this? And is there a proper work around rather than me hacking about XML config files? Bear in mind I've been using Java for about a week. I know nothing about ANT/Java really.

Comment: ***Possibly*** related to [Java applet dependencies fetched multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15029510/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Use `http://fproject.localhost/getjava` as the codebase on the `jnlp` element
- Use a relative path on the resources (i.e. `<jar href="libs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>`)
- Don't put `main="true"` everywhere, but only the jar containing the main class `Windows8.Windows8GUI`

Comment: Removing the main="true" yields yet another message. They shouldn't have been there anyway I know, that was a copy paste error. The new error is presented after the jars are loaded: http://i49.tinypic.com/2iths7.png. It is also worth noting that removing the libs and leaving just the main class fixes the no cache issue. But obviously, I need them.

Comment: Did you try clearing the Java application cache after changing the JNLP file?

Comment: Didn't know that was possible. Th problem there being that the JNLP is changed each time it is loaded, it is updated with a new hash in the URL for the main class Jar. Is it possible to stop caching?

Comment: More info: If I disable "keep temporary files on my computer" in the Java control panel applet then the app launches fine. The problem with the incorrect URL's still persisits. How/why the hell is it changing my url's!